# Reading string with spaces from file in c

Tags: c, string, file, parsing, file-io

I have a question about reading a string containing spaces from a file.
Here is my function that reads data from file and writes it to array of structures.
However, if the input for the first string contains two strings and space between them, then the first string goes to the first parameter and the second string goes to the second parameter.
How to split the line from a file in such a way that necessary data goes to specified fields of structure?
Thank you!

```
void readFileToDiary(FILE* file, drivingDiary* diaryTemp){

    int i = 0;

    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        printf("\nError opening file!\n");
    else{
        while (!feof(file)){
            fscanf(file, "%s %s %d %s %s %d", diaryTemp[i].locationStart,
                diaryTemp[i].timeStart, &diaryTemp[i].odometerStart,
                diaryTemp[i].locationEnd, diaryTemp[i].timeEnd,
                &diaryTemp[i].odometerEnd);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**
line inside the file contains:
some place 13:40 10000 some other place 14:45 10120

So,

```
      "some place" -> first field of structure,
             13:40 -> second field,
             10000 -> third field,
"some other place" -> fourth field,
             14:45 -> fifth filed,
             10120 -> sixth field.
```

**UPD** Working version is here (without fscanf() check)!

```
void readFileToDiary(FILE* file, drivingDiary* diary){

    int i = 0;

    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        printf("\nError opening file!\n");
    else{
        while(fscanf(file, " %[a-zA-Z ]%[0-9:]%d %[a-zA-Z ]%[0-9:]%d%*[\n]",
                diary[i].locationStart,
                diary[i].timeStart,
                &diary[i].odometerStart,
                diary[i].locationEnd,
                diary[i].timeEnd,
                &diary[i].odometerEnd) != EOF)
            i++;        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about doing a `getLine` or a `fgets` to get an entire line from file than use `strtok` to get each field separated by space?

Comment: Use `fgets()/sscanf()`.  `char buf[100]; while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL)) { if (sscanf(buf, "%s %s %d %s %s %d", ...) != 6) Handle_FormatError(); ... }`

Comment: The fundamental issue is you are loosely using 4 definitions of _string_.  1) text file lines that are terminated with `'\n'`, 2) grouped of characters separated with "space between them", 3) using `"%s"` which scans groups of `char` separated with _white-space_ (not only `' '`) and trying to save these three as 4) C strings, array of `char` terminated and including a `'\0'`.  Suggest being more explicit on your goal or give a number of examples.

Comment: strtok is a good one, thanks! But I still don't get the logic of the process. Since the number of strings in the first parameter varies and is not specified I don't understand how to split the line and group it again.

Comment: Maybe a double pass to determines how many tokens where found. And if it was greater than field numbers, then you concat two consecutive tokens to fill one field. But if strings with more than one spaces were used than it would be a trouble.

Comment: The problem is that the first and the fourth parameters may vary in number of strings with spaces.

Comment: try to create a new file and write the same structure data ie `drivingDiary` and read from that file then it may solve your problem.

Comment: @chux, I have added an example

Comment: Maybe separate on context `" %[a-zA-Z ]%[0-9:]%d %[a-zA-Z ]%[0-9:]%d"`, but this will have trailing spaces in `locationStart` and `locationEnd`.  Be sure to test `fscanf()` result.  Code will certainly need to use something other than just `fscanf()` to fully meet you goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @chux! this "%[a-zA-Z ]%[0-9:]%d %[a-zA-Z ]%[0-9:]%d" actually helped. However in this case there was '\n' left at the beginning of each next line but using getc(file) solved the problem.

Comment: Note, your comment's format differs from mine (leading space). ... or use `" %[a-zA-Z ]%[0-9:]%d %[a-zA-Z ]%[0-9:]%d%*[\n]"` to consume trailing new-lines.  BTW: the way you are using `feof()` is wrong.  Instead, when the `fscanf()` result is `EOF`, file is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the number of spaces in the start and end locations is unknown, will be complex using a scanf() method.  However, it can be parsed using a more 'old-school' method....

```
"some place 13:40 10000 some other place 14:45 10120"
```

First, think of each line as containing two 'way-points'; a 'start', and and 'end'.  Then simplify the parsing individual way-points by using a single "way-point" parsing method.

```
"some place 13:40 10000", "some other place 14:45 10120"
```

So, there would be several ways to build the 'way-point' parser.  As I looked at the problem, I didn't want to start out using a space character as a delimiter.  I wanted to find some other starting point.

Each way-point contains a ':' character, so I started there.  From the ':' character I went left, to find the space, and converted the space to a '\0' string termination character.  That isolated the 'location' of the waypoint.

Then, from the ':', I went right, to find the space, and converted the space to a '\0' string termination character.  That isolated the 'time' of the waypoint.

The odometer portion of the waypoint is easily isolated using strtoul().

My code follows here:

```
/***************************************************************************
** Compiler setup
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct DRIVING_WAYPOINT_S
   {
   char *location;
   char *time;
   long  odometer;
   } DRIVING_WAYPOINT_T;

typedef struct DRIVING_DIARY_S
   {
   DRIVING_WAYPOINT_T start;
   DRIVING_WAYPOINT_T end;
   } DRIVING_DIARY_T;

/***************************************************************************
** Parse a waypoint.
*/
int ParseRecord(
      char                *I__string,
      char               **_O_string,
      DRIVING_WAYPOINT_T  *I__waypoint
      )
   {
   int rCode=0;
   char *cp, *space;

   /* Parse location */
   cp=strchr(I__string, ':'); /* Find the first ocurrance of ':' */
   if(NULL == cp)
      {
      rCode=EINVAL;
      fprintf(stderr, "Parse error.  Time does not contain a ':'\n");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   space = cp;
   while(' ' != *space)
      --space;

   *space = '\0';
   I__waypoint->location = strdup(I__string);

   /* Parse time */
   cp = space + 1;
   space=strchr(cp, ' ');
   if(NULL == space)
      {
      rCode=EINVAL;
      fprintf(stderr, "Parse error.  No space following time\n");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   *space='\0';
   I__waypoint->time = strdup(cp);

   /* Parse odometer */
   cp = space+1;
   I__waypoint->odometer = strtol(cp, &cp, 10);
   while(' ' == *cp)
      ++cp;

   if(_O_string)
      *_O_string = cp;

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }

/*******************************************************************************
** Parse the diary file. 
*/
int ReadFileToDiary(
      FILE             *I__fp,
      DRIVING_DIARY_T **IO_diary,
      int              *IO_diaryEntries
      )
   {
   int rCode = 0;
   char line[255+1];

   for(;;)
      {
      DRIVING_DIARY_T *tmp;
      char *cp;

      /* Read the next line from the file. */
      errno=0;
      if(NULL == fgets(line, sizeof(line), I__fp))
         {
         if(feof(I__fp))
            break;

         rCode=errno;
         fprintf(stderr, "fgets() reports: %d.\n", errno);
         goto CLEANUP;
         }

      /* Expand the diary array for one more entry. */
      tmp=realloc(*IO_diary, ((*IO_diaryEntries)+1) * sizeof(DRIVING_DIARY_T));
      if(NULL == tmp)
         {
         rCode=ENOMEM;
         fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed.\n");
         goto CLEANUP;
         }
      *IO_diary = tmp;
      memset(&(*IO_diary)[*IO_diaryEntries], '\0', sizeof(DRIVING_DIARY_T));

      /* Check for empty string. */
      if('\0' == *line)
         continue;

      /* Parse the 'start' waypoint. */
      rCode=ParseRecord(line, &cp, &(*IO_diary)[*IO_diaryEntries].start);
      if(rCode)
         {
         fprintf(stderr, "ParseRecord(start) reports: %d\n", rCode);
         goto CLEANUP;
         }

      /* Parse the 'end' waypoint. */
      rCode=ParseRecord(cp, NULL, &(*IO_diary)[*IO_diaryEntries].end);
      if(rCode)
         {
         fprintf(stderr, "ParseRecord(end) reports: %d\n", rCode);
         goto CLEANUP;
         }

      /* Increment the 'diary entries' counter. */
      (*IO_diaryEntries)++;
      }

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);   
   }

/*******************************************************************************
** Free the diary array.
*/
int DiaryFree(
      DRIVING_DIARY_T *diary,
      int              diaryEntries
      )
   {
   int rCode=0;
   int nCnt;

   for(nCnt=0; nCnt<diaryEntries; ++nCnt)
      {
      free(diary[nCnt].start.location);
      free(diary[nCnt].end.location);
      free(diary[nCnt].start.time);
      free(diary[nCnt].end.time);         
     }

   free(diary);   

   return(rCode);
   }

/*******************************************************************************
** Program start.  
*/
int main()
   {
   int              rCode        = 0;
   FILE            *fp           = NULL;
   DRIVING_DIARY_T *diary        = NULL;
   int              diaryEntries = 0;
   int              nCnt;

   /* Open the data file. */
   errno=0;
   fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   if(NULL == fp)
      {
      rCode=errno;   
      fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

    /* Parse the file into the dynamic diary array. */
    rCode=ReadFileToDiary(fp, &diary, &diaryEntries);
    if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "ReadFileToDiary() reports: %d\n", rCode);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

    /* Print out the array. */
    for(nCnt=0; nCnt < diaryEntries; ++nCnt)
      {
      printf("[%d] %s %s %ld %s %s %ld\n",
         nCnt,
         diary[nCnt].start.location,
         diary[nCnt].start.time,
         diary[nCnt].start.odometer,
         diary[nCnt].end.location,
         diary[nCnt].end.time,
         diary[nCnt].end.odometer
         );
       }

CLEANUP:

   if(diary)
      DiaryFree(diary, diaryEntries);

   if(fp)
      fclose(fp);

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Lots of good code here.  1) Why `while (!feof(I__fp)) {`?  Why not `while (1) { ... if (NULL == fgets(line, sizeof(line), I__fp)) { if (feof(I__fp)) break;`.  2) Suggest move the `realloc()` to _after_ a successful `fgets()`?  3) `while(' ' != *space) --space;` is a problem is there is no preceding space.

Comment: @chux, thank you for your review. To your points 1) and 2), you are correct.  Perhaps I was overly focused on the parsing aspect; and not so much on the reading of file lines, or the efficiency of the array size.  However, I edited the code and addressed these two points.

Comment: @chux, As for 3), I believe that there is (most likely) a space prior to the ':' character (ie:"some place 13:40 10000") between 'place' and '13'.

Comment: Agree about a likely preceding space.  The rest of the code has good error checking and that check seemed reasonable without being pedantic.  +1 for the good work

Comment: Well, it seems quite complicated to me so far... Have anybody checked whether it is working? If so, I probably should mark this answer as a solution of the problem.

Comment: @m_danylov.  Sorry about the complexity.  I compiled it with gcc on Linux SLES 11. It ran as expected.